React Loader Spinner color not change
I have a Next.js project. I will make React-loader-spinner using animation. But the animation color is not working. I added inline styling, custom class, but it still uses the default value. How can I solve it
I want to change the component color change.
            <RotatingLines
                visible={true}
                height="36"
                width="36"
                color="gray"
                strokeWidth="5"
                animationDuration="0.75"
                ariaLabel="rotating-lines-loading"
                wrapperStyle={{}}
                wrapperClass=""
                style={{ stroke: '#fff' }}
                className="text-white stroke-white"
            />


From where are you importing the component RotatingLines from??

@jarivak If you are asking about the package I used, I used this one. link If you are asking as React code, this is how to use it import { RotatingLines } from "react-loader-spinner"

For changing color at <RotatingLines /> component you need to add strokeColor property.
See working preview here - https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-spinner-2gf9jl?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A8%2C21
Documentation of available props can be found here - https://mhnpd.github.io/react-loader-spinner/docs/components/rotating-lines
Code snippet attaching bellow
<RotatingLines
  visible
  height="36"
  width="36"
  strokeWidth="5"
  strokeColor="gray"
  animationDuration="0.75"
  ariaLabel="rotating-lines-loading"
  className="text-white stroke-white"
/>

